# How to build an algorithm where I need to "store" multiple indexes

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I don't know how to technically explain the problem ( only been in this game for 3 months) but I'll frame it and hope you guys can manage to solve it because I'm out of ideas for this

So I want to start at list0 and then check if some element is in list1. If it is then we "track" that element through the lists to see the final "transformation(s)"

Rule1:  The elements on list1 "transform" into the element of list2 that has the same index in the list

Rule2: one element can transform into multiple elements, so it can appear more than once on list1

Exemple:  "1" is in index's 0 and 4 so it transforms into "1a" and "1bb", then "1a" is in index's 1 and 8 so it trasforms into "2b" and "7a" etc.

So basically tracking "1" gives us the information that "1" turned into five final elements ( "1bb", "4d", "7a", "91", "92" ) and tracking "2z" gives us just "3z" (path 2z-2zz-3z)

I started with the code bellow but I get stuck because I have no clue on how to "safe" and iterate the indexes of "middle" elements...

No idea if this is the right way to solve it

```
list0 = ['1', '2z', 'etc']
list1 = ['1', '1a', '2b', '3c', "1", "1bb","2z", "2zz","1a",'2b',"100","100"]
list2 = ['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d', "1bb", "8", "2zz", "3z", "7a","100", "91","92" ]


for item in list0:
if item in list1:
    alpha_key = item
    indexes = [i for i, k in enumerate(list1) if k == alpha_key]
    for i in indexes:
        alpha_key = list1[i]
        keep_going = True
        while alpha_key in list1 and keep_going:
            alpha_key = list2[i]
            if alpha_key in list1:
                print("INDEXES IS ", indexes)
                keep_going = True
                i += 1
            if alpha_key not in list1:
                print("this is resulting ", alpha_key, "of this ", item)
                keep_going = False
```

Comment: I believe you need to more clearly express your desired result. What do you mean by "track"? How is list2 composed? What's the logic that index 4 becomes 1bb, or even more importantly 1 into '7a' which appears to have no commonality with the original number?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a step back.  What you have in `list1` and `list2` is an input and its corresponding output, so let's group those together into a single list, so we don't have to worry about indexes so much.  We can then create a function that will take a *single* input, and find the corresponding output simply.  You then have `list0` which is a list of inputs to transform into their outputs.  [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will make this simpler.

```
list0 = ['1', '2z', 'etc']
list1 = ['1', '1a', '2b', '3c', "1", "1bb","2z", "2zz","1a",'2b',"100","100"]
list2 = ['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d', "1bb", "8", "2zz", "3z", "7a","100", "91","92" ]

transforms = list(zip(list1, list2))

def transform(value):
    return [v[1] for v in transforms if v[0] == value]

result = [transform(x) for x in list0]
```

`result` ends up with the value `[['1a', '1bb'], ['2zz'], []]`.

The [zip function](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) was used to create a correspondence (a list of pairs) between `list1` and `list2`. The `transform` function then goes through these pairs and finds all of them where the first element (which came from `list1`) matches the input, and selects the second element (which is the corresponding element from `list2`.  It returns all such elements as a list, in the order they appeared.  So if we were to pass it `'1'`, it would return `['1a', '1bb']`, or if we passed it `'2b'` it would return `['3c']`.  If it is passed a value that is *not in* `list1`, it will return an empty list.

The final list comprehension applies this function to every element of `list0`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursion to solve this. What you do is recursively check if a value is in list1 (starting from a value in list0). If you find one, then you can recursively check if the value in list2 with the same index is in list1. If it's not, you know it's the last value.

```
list0 = ['1', '2z', 'etc']
list1 = ['1', '1a', '2b', '3c', "1", "1bb","2z", "2zz","1a",'2b',"100","100"]
list2 = ['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d', "1bb", "8", "2zz", "3z", "7a","100", "91","92" ]

def findPath(val):
    path = {val}
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[i] == val:
            morePath = findPath(list2[i])
            for elem in morePath:
                path.add(elem)
            if list1[i] in path:
                path.remove(list1[i])

    return path

for i in list0:
    print(findPath(i))
```

One thing to note is that you have to remove the current index that you check since you know that it's not the ending index.
This works well if there are no loops in the lists, EG 1 -> 1a -> 1a, will result in an infinite loop. Another problem could be if you have a long chain of transformation, which might cause a recursive stack overflow.

Here is another solution that I believe to be more correct. It is using a Queue to know what the next value to check is. Additionally, it only checks the same value only once by checking if it is in the set.

One thing that I am not sure of is if this is the right way for transformation. It seems like list1 contains "1bb" which you said is a final element. Is this correct, or should it be "8" instead?

```
from queue import Queue

list0 = ['1', '2z', 'etc']
list1 = ['1', '1a', '2b', '3c', "1", "1bb","2z", "2zz","1a",'2b',"100","100"]
list2 = ['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d', "1bb", "8", "2zz", "3z", "7a","100", "91","92" ]

checked = set()
checkQueue = Queue()

def findPath(val):
    path = set()
    checkQueue.put(val)
    while checkQueue.qsize() > 0:
        curVal = checkQueue.get()
        if curVal in checked:
            continue
        checked.add(curVal)
        path.add(curVal)
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            if list1[i] == curVal:
                if list1[i] in path:
                    path.remove(curVal)
                checkQueue.put(list2[i])

    return path

for i in list0:
    print(findPath(i))
```

What the second solution solves is the both the looping problem (so that the program doesn't crash), which will output no values in the loop, and the recursive problem since it's doing it iteratively.